# Trusty Server not upgrading

Tags: 14.04, server, apt, upgrade, updates

I have a 32 bit Trusty server I would like to upgrade, but it wont do it.
I have update mangager installed, and I give this command:

```
$sudo do-release-upgrade 
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found
```

I have also run `sudo apt-get update, and sudo apt-get upgrade`, but it doesn't help. How can I upgrade to server Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: You should also run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` as the it upgrades all things needing upgrading such as the kernel, whereas the other command does not.

Comment: I had run that too, but it also wasnt doing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the first point release of Ubuntu 16.04 is not out yet, attempting to upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS without using the `-d` option will fail. The `-d` option is needed to specify that you want to "upgrade to the latest devel release". In short, you need to specify the `-d` option:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

Comment: That will be marked solved, as soon as time allows. Many thanks, despite the warning against leaving thanks type comments.

Comment: That's not going to upgrade him to 16.10 though is it as it says "the latest devel release"?

Comment: The 16.04-to-16.10 upgrade would happen if OP does `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` in 16.04, but I don't think there is a direct upgrade path from 14.04 LTS to 16.10.